# dyld: Library not loaded for (xcrun altool)

Tags: xcode, macos, app-store-connect, dyld, xcrun

I use `xcrun altool` command to connect app store. But the command always fails with below errors.

**Environment:-**

```
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.15.7
BuildVersion:   19H1922

$ xcodebuild -version
Xcode 11.6
Build version 11E708

$ xcode-select -v
xcode-select version 2373.

$ xcode-select -p
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

$ xcrun --version
xcrun version 50.
```

I'm getting this error when trying to run `xcrun altool` on terminal.

**Error:-**

```
$ xcrun altool
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/ITunesConnectFoundation.framework/Versions/A/ITunesConnectFoundation
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/altool
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

The above command expected output would be something like below.

```
Error: code -1003 (No command was specified. Unable to run altool.)
```

How am I able to resolve this issue? Any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing first, `altool` is deprecating, consider moving to `notarytool` as soon as possible. See [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/customizing_the_notarization_workflow/notarizing_apps_when_developing_with_xcode_12_and_earlier)

And both your Xcode version and your macOS version are far too old, my Xcode is 13.4.1 already. So I doubt whether App Store can accept connections from your Xcode version.

For your question, if you want a quick fix, just upgrade your macOS and the Xcode app. Or you can check whether your framework is missing at: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ITunesConnectFoundation.framework`, may be a reinstall of your current Xcode version.

Comment: Thanks a lot kakaiikaka, I have re-installed my current `Xcode` version then the problem has been vanished.

Comment: I was supprized your Xcode version still works with app store! LoL